# Force exact parameters match

Tags: c#, function

Having a class `Base` and a class `Derived : Base`, how to implement a function

```
void Foo(Base obj) { } // Must be restricted to Base type
```

where this code compiles

```
var obj = new Base();
Foo(obj);
```

but this code doesn't?

```
var obj = new Derived();
Foo(obj);
```

Comment: Thus breaking one of the core concepts of object oriented programming? Why do you want this?

Comment: Doesn't it violate SOLID? ("L" - Liskov Substitution Principle)

Comment: What if `Derived` is an *exact copy* of `Base` - `public class Derived: Base {}`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yep, pretty sure it violates the Liskov Principle. Anyway I want to know if there is a syntax that allows to force the exact matching. Also I don't want to change the defined types. So Derived must extends Base.

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense from an object-oriented perspective. As every `Derived` **is** also a `Base`, why should it not be permitted to provide it to your method? In fact your method should not even care for the exact type at all.

Comment: Can you split `Base` into `abstract class AbstractBase` and `sealed class RealBase : AbstractBase`, with `Derived` continuing to derive from `AbstractBase`?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever well it's not about design. It's more about c# capabilities. I want to know if there is a way to define such function without changing the types.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever And also a "no" could be an accepted answer :)

Comment: Actually this is possible, you'd have to create a code analyzer and implement your custom rules, but as others have said, makes no sense. Have a look at Roslyn extensions.

Comment: As mentioned before it wouldn't make any sense, but you could always check the exact type at runtime `obj.GetType() == typeof(BaseClass)`.

Comment: Seems like you actually have some completely different problem of which you think, restricting your member to the base-type is the solution. What probolem do you try to solve by that code? What´s the purpose behind that?

Comment: @HimBromBeere It's not a real problem. I'm not even trying to use this approach in my code. It's just a question popped out yesterday with some colleagues and I just wanted to know is such behaviour is achievable. Just that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can´t restrict a method to only accepts parameters of a certain type **at compile-time**, unless that type is `sealed`. In fact that would break any object-oriented principle, as an instance of a derived type is allways an instance of the base-class. On the other hand your `Foo`-method shouldn´t care for that at all, as it does not know anything of the derived type. All it gets is an argument of type `Base`, which can or cannot be of a derived type.

At runtime you could of course get the actual type and throw an exception for the case of `Derived`:

```
public void Foo(Base @base)
{
    if(@base.GetType() != typeof(Base))
        throw new NotSupportedException("must be of type Base");
}
```

As an aside: `base` is a reserved keyword and can´t be used as name for a variable.  Thus I added the verbatim (`@`) into the code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that in C#.

But you can check the type of param in your method and do the actions you want.
[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J09kJh)

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var derived = new Derived();
        var b = new Base();
        D(derived); //Derived
        D(b); //Base
    }

    public static void D(Base base)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(base.GetType());

    }
```

Comment: That will still compile for both types. Btw.: `base` is a reserved keyword, and hus can´t be used as symbol. You may use `@base` however.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I said we can't do something like OP expect.But an alternative way is proposed in my answer.